# would like to know why null is passed at declaration?

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER procedure [Production].[ScrapReason_search]
 ( 
  @scrapreasonid as int=null, 
 @startdate as datetime,  @enddate  as datetime
  ) 
as
 begin 
 select * from Production.ScrapReason  
 where modifieddate between @startdate and @enddate and     
       scrapreasonid = @scrapreasonid    OR
       ISNULL(@scrapreasonid, '') = ''
end
```

why null is passed to variable @scrapreasonid ? 
i tried case logic for above SP it didnt worked. i understand that the final logic is when @scrapreasonid values is not passed then return all rows. but my question is that if we pass the null at decalaration. then again why it is taking other values for this @scrapreason variable which im passing while execution. i'm not passing null instead i'm passing a values for that parameter.

Comment: You just need some parentheses around `and (scrapreasonid = @scrapreasonid OR ISNULL(@scrapreasonid, '') = '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question "would like to know why null is passed at declaration?" the answer is, it does not mean that always parameter will have NULL. While calling this procedure if we pass the value for parameter "scrapreasonid" then it takes that value. In case no values are passed, it will take the default value we have declared i.e. NULL

Answer (score 1):

It makes the parameter optional. By default `NULL` value will b passed when there is no value passed to the parameter when the procedure is executed

When the procedure is called it is not mandatory that `@scrapreasonid` paramater should be passed with some value

Currently your query is executed like this

```
where (modifieddate between @startdate and @enddate and scrapreasonid = @scrapreasonid)
  OR  ISNULL(@scrapreasonid, '') = ''
```

Because `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` so it will be evaluated first then OR will evaluated so you are not getting any result.

To handle `NULL` value try this.

```
select * from Production.ScrapReason 
 where modifieddate between @startdate and @enddate and  
(scrapreasonid = @scrapreasonid OR @scrapreasonid IS NULL)
```

Comment: any how i got the answer. as it takes default value when im not passing the parameter.         my query executes well as their is no null values in my table.